# Imitate web form with wget

Tags: javascript, forms

A website has a web form backed by aspx.  We are trying to use bash or perl with wget to imitate filling out and submitting the webform.  This means crafting a URL of the form `www.thatsite.com/someform.aspx?a=b&c=d` that will get the site to return the result as if we typed in the data manually.

The webform's Submit button source looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$btnSearch"
 value="Search" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
 WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$btnSearch&quot;,
 &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;CriteriaGroup&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, 
 false))" id="ContentPlaceHolder2_btnSearch" />
```

In the JS console we have tried DoPostBackWithOptions(), which calls __DoPostBack():

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

If the values are filled out in the form, this works from the javascript console in Chrome's developer's tools:

```
__doPostBack(new 
WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$btnSearch", 
"", true, "CriteriaGroup", "", false, false).eventTarget, new
WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$btnSearch", "", true,
"CriteriaGroup", "", false, false).eventArgument)
```

What we can't figure out is how to see exactly what URL is being sent back to the server from `theForm.submit()`.

Edit: I see we will need `wget --postdata="a=b&c=d"`, not the get syntax I described above.  still need to see what the post data is though.

Comment: I would suggest using a headless browser for that like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). It is more convenient and also executes javascript.

Comment: Thank you but we don't know javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Chrome Developer tools to get that request for you. Go to network tab and make sure logging is enabled, than you submit the form on the webpage, it should log a (probably) POST request there. Right click and Copy -> as CURL:

[image: copy as curl]

If the network pane is cleared after submitting you may need to enable `Preserve log` checkbox

Comment: Thanks, never thought of r-click in that context.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Chrome (or Safari or Firefox) web inspector to inspect what values are submitted to the server when you submit the form with JavaScript. Once you see that, you'll be able to copy it in your script.